# Suppress Reminder in Windows Phone and instead Simulate Navigation from within code

Tags: windows-phone-8, reminders

In Windows Phone, the reminder is usually used for scheduled notifications. The reminder when popped up, requires user to click the reminder pop up in order to navigate to specific page and do certain action. 
Can we simulate or suppress this reminder programatically when occured and instead perform the action it was supposed to execute when actually clicked. This would be of great use to user.

Any help, suggestions or ideas on the same?.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible. A Windows Phone application has very limited interaction with the system when it isn't running in the foreground.

If you're trying to bypass the reminder to display something (for instance, a page of your application) without user interaction, then you have no way of doing that.

If it's just about updating some data or calling a webservice without displaying anything, you should use a background agent instead of a reminder.

Windows Phone was built around the idea of letting the user in control at all time. That's why there is no way of forcing the user to navigate to a page of your application if it wasn't running in first place.

Comment: I have a scheduled notification which should pop up at scheduled date and time. Hence I have used a reminder. Now if the Date and Time is already set by a user, then rather than requiring user interaction to click the reminder, we can just suppress it and simulate navigation to the required app page, and perform the action intended to do by the user.

Comment: @Siddharth Still, wouldn't the reminder be useful? I don't know what your application is doing, but imagine I have set a specific date and time, and the phone is in my pocket at that precise time. How are you going to warn me if the action is triggered automatically?

Comment: I have made an SMS type app, where user schedules the message to be sent at scheduled date and time. A reminder is used as the user would be notified at exactly the scheduled time. After the user clicks the reminder, he would be navigated to the SMS page. But yeah here too the user has to deal with SMSComposeTask. But yeah if I could some how suppress it, toeither perform another different action like.

Comment: @Siddharth You're stuck both ways here: there is no way to display the SMS page without user interaction if your application isn't running on foreground, and once on the SMS page there is no way to send it without user interaction.